# react component is hiding behind the page in the website

Tags: java, html, css, reactjs, z-index

Im having difficulty with this project of mine. But in the picture below, when you press the plus(+) button a window is supposed to appear below which it did but it is being covered up by another section of page. The pop up window is a react component which I can show you in the code below. Please do tell me of how to solve this problem.

```
const Test = () => (
  <UncontrolledDropdown nav className="list-inline-item quickadd-dropdown">
    <DropdownToggle nav className="p-0">
      <Tooltip title="Add" placement="bottom">
        <IconButton aria-label="plus">
          <Add fontSize="small" />
        </IconButton>
      </Tooltip>
    </DropdownToggle>
    <DropdownMenu>
      <div className="dropdown-content py-5">
        <div className="dropdown-top d-flex justify-content-between rounded-top bg-secondary">
          <span className="text-white font-weight-bold">Add</span>
        </div>
        <Scrollbars
          className="rct-scroll"
          autoHeight
          autoHeightMin={100}
          autoHeightMax={350}
        >
          <ul className="list-unstyled mb-0 dropdown-list">
            {links.map((link, key) => (
              <li key={key}>
                <NavLink to={link.link}>
                  <IntlMessages id={link.title} />
                </NavLink>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </Scrollbars>
      </div>
    </DropdownMenu>
  </UncontrolledDropdown>
);

export default Test;
```

[image]

Comment: give the higher index higher than your sibling

Answer (score 0):

Try using higher zIndex for the element that you want to show above the other element and lower the index for the one who should be shown below:

```
style={{zIndex: 1000}} - for the above element
style={{zIndex: 900}} - for the below element
```